# How to offset an array by n * row + col in MIPS?

Tags: mips

Let's say you're representing a 2d array as a 1d array. You can get an element from said array by doing:

```
array[n * row + col]
```

Where n is the width, but in this case assume the height and width are the same, so it can just be n. I may be overthinking this, but I can't think of any way one can do this. You can't offset by a register. I could easily perform the operations and store them in registers, but I'm not sure where to go from there because of that.

How could I offset the array by this?

Edit: I did some digging and found a question that I think is similar [Adding offset to base from register in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545896/adding-offset-to-base-from-register-in-mips)

I modified it to this problem. Would this be correct?

```
mul     $t0, $s0, $s1 # n * row
add     $t1, $t0, $s2 # (n * row) + col
sll     $t1, $t1, 2
add     $s3, $s3, $t1
lw      $v0, 0($s3)
```

Comment: _"Would this be correct?"_ Looks about right to me.

Comment: @Michael In my program, I have been having issues with accessing nonexistent memory. I was wondering if you had any suggestions for how I could determine if the cause of that is from within this function or not? I tried removing the sll line and I then have unaligned memory, which makes sense. But I'm getting the impression that I'm almost going outside the bounds of the array or something like that.